# Call Apex class method on the fly (dynamically)

Tags: apex

Is there any way I can call apex method from class if both class name and method are stored in the string.

```
String strClass = 'BatchUtil';
String strMethod = 'updateAccounts'
```

now I want to call above method.. is it possible ?

I was doing research and came across following - (not sure how this works and how to call it from salesforce)

```
ExecuteAnonymousResult[] = binding.executeanonymous(string apexcode);
```

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/sforce_api_calls_executeanonymous.htm

Comment: Please see this link for step by step instructions of how dynamic apex (class and method) can be achieved using Callable Interface. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/297847/dynamic-class-invocation-in-trigger-callable-interface It is detailed solution based on what Clint mentioned below.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With the [Callable interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_System_Callable.htm#apex_interface_System_Callable) that was introduced in Winter '19 you can now build a light weight interface for the methods you want to dynamically call from a class.

The example below is from the docs (tweaked to show dynamic method naming):

**Example class you want to dynamically call**

```
public class Extension implements Callable {

   // Actual method
   String concatStrings(String stringValue) {
     return stringValue + stringValue;
   }

   // Actual method
   Decimal multiplyNumbers(Decimal decimalValue) {
     return decimalValue * decimalValue;
   }

   // Dispatch actual methods
   public Object call(String action, Map<String, Object> args) {
     switch on action {
       when 'concatStrings' {
         return this.concatStrings((String)args.get('stringValue'));
       }
       when 'multiplyNumbers' {
         return this.multiplyNumbers((Decimal)args.get('decimalValue'));
       }
       when else {
        throw new ExtensionMalformedCallException('Method not implemented');
       }
     }
   }

   public class ExtensionMalformedCallException extends Exception {}
}
```

**Unit test demonstrating the dynamic calling**

```
@IsTest
private with sharing class ExtensionCaller {

   @IsTest
   private static void givenConfiguredExtensionWhenCalledThenValidResult() {

      // Given
      String className = 'Extension'; // Variable to demonstrate setting class name
      String methodName = 'multiplyNumbers'; // Variable to demonstrate setting method name
      Decimal decimalTestValue = 10;

      // When
      Callable extension = (Callable) Type.forName(className).newInstance();
      Decimal result = (Decimal) extension.call(methodName, new Map<String, Object> { 'decimalValue' => decimalTestValue });

      // Then
      System.assertEquals(100, result);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Client for pointing out Callable interface. I have expanded beyond Salesforce documentation for end-to-end automation: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/297847/dynamic-class-invocation-in-trigger-callable-interface Your thoughts / feedback?

Comment: I have actually been struggling to decide when this is actually useful.  If I'm going to give someone a list of actions and arguments, I might as well give them an interface.  I have been trying to come up with a clever way to use this to resolve the dependencies issues.  e.g. I have a core package, I made the mistake of putting in common interfaces.  How do I move it into the correct package, without breaking dependencies...

Answer (score 45):

While you can instantiate a class based on its name using the Type system class, you can't dynamically locate a method and execute it.  The best that you can do is to dynamically create an instance of a class that implements an interface and execute one of the methods on the interface.

There's more information on the Type class and an example in the :

[Apex Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_type.htm)

Comment: There's an idea for this at:

http://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrVaAAK

Comment: From the instance method, you could, of course, just call the static method you originally wanted to call.

Comment: this is awesome never thought about this approch.. thanks a lot Bob and Metadaddy...  and thanks a ton to stackexchange as well.  I am going to implement this approach now and will post my code so that others can benefit from it.

Comment: Good suggestion Bob on using interface based approach to achieve this requirement.

Comment: This is a good related read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern. I'm going to post one of my Apex class factory implementations as a question/answer.

Comment: Here it is: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1116/dynamic-execution-of-classes-in-apex

Comment: @BobBuzzard Could you please update the link to type class, it is pointing to APEX developer guide.

Comment: @CODEPirate done.

Answer (score 12):

Now this is possible in apex using Tooling API.

```
> ToolingAPI x = new ToolingAPI(); ToolingAPI.ExecuteAnonymousResult
> toolingResult = x.executeAnonymousUnencoded("Your apex code as a
> string here");
```

Please refer blog post - http://codefriar.wordpress.com/2014/10/30/eval-in-apex-secure-dynamic-code-evaluation-on-the-salesforce1-platform/

ToolingAPI class is taken from here - https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi/blob/apex-toolingapi-rest/src/classes/ToolingAPI.cls

Comment: There is the `executeAnonymousUnencoded` method coming from? The Tooling API has an `executeAnonymous` operation in the WSDL. Is the Unencoded part something from how you implemented it in Apex?

Comment: @DanielBallinger I just updated answer to add this info

Comment: Is there a synchronous way to execute a method so that I can read the response and act on it in my bigger/larger process?

Answer (score 10):

**Update**

Based on Kevin's post about [adding EVAL() in Apex](http://executeAnonymousUnencoded) I created a variation that parses the response out of the Debug log. This uses the Apex API rather than the Tooling API. See [Adding Eval() support to Apex](http://www.fishofprey.com/2014/11/adding-eval-support-to-apex.html).

With this you can do things like:

```
string output = soapSforceCom200608Apex.evalString('string first = \'foo\'; string second = \'bar\'; string result = first + second; System.debug(LoggingLevel.Error, result);');  
System.assertEquals('foobar', output);  
System.debug(output);
```

---

The answer to [How to use/invoke "execute Anonymous" calls from Apex/Controller](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/How-to-use-invoke-quot-execute-Anonymous-quot-calls-from-Apex/td-p/128486) is:

> You can't invoke executeAnonymous from another block of Apex.  Execute anonymous is a separate entry point to compile & run a routine which can only be invoked through the API verb -  see the apex WSDL: /services/wsdl/apex

So you could in theory import the Apex WSDL back into Salesforce, which would give you `binding` from your example. Then you just need to build up a string with the Apex code that you would pass into the execute anonymous method. See update above for sample implementation.

You could use the article [Calling Salesforce Web Services Using Apex](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/calling-salesforce-web-services-using-apex) as an example, substituting the apex WSDL for the partner API WSDL.

Comment: good point, I think this approach can work well for methods that return nothing i.e. VOID return type